# Make dropdown into jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have a few dropdowns created by plugins on wordpress and I am trying to make them into sliders.

I found this page here -- http://jqueryui.com/slider/#hotelrooms

Im trying to adapt the code to my needs --

```
<script>
 jQuery(function($) {
    var select = $( ".comment-overall_r select" );
    var slider = $( "<div id='slider'></div>" ).insertAfter( select ).slider({
      min: 1,
      max: 5,
      range: "min",
      value: select[ 50 ].selectedIndex + 1,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        select[ 0 ].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
      }
    });
    $( ".comment-overall_r select" ).change(function() {
      slider.slider( "value", this.selectedIndex + 1 );
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Nothing is happening and I keep receiving an error about selectedIndex. The select dropdowns are generated by the plugin so I do not to edit them directly.
How can I do this?

Comment: "I keep receiving an error" What is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why you have added configuration like `value: select[ 50 ]`. I think the configuration should be like:

```
 var slider = $( "<div id='slider'></div>" ).insertAfter( select ).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 6,
    range: "min",
    value: select[ 0 ].selectedIndex + 1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
    select[ 0 ].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. If I want to add multiple classes though is that possible? `jQuery(function($) {
    var select = $( ".comment-overall_r select, .comment-overall_n_r select" );
  var slider = $( "<div id='slider'></div>" ).insertAfter( select ).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 6,
    range: "min",
    value: select[ 0 ].selectedIndex + 1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
    select[ 0 ].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
  }
});
    $( ".comment-overall_r select, .comment-overall_n_r select" ).change(function() {
      slider.slider( "value", this.selectedIndex + 1 );
    });
  });`

Comment: Thanks. Multiple select boxes to single slider is not valid scenario. There has to be single slider associated with each select box. Just imagine slider as horizontally displayed options of select box.

Comment: Ok so I will have to rewrite the same function multiple times but just renamed specific variables ie. 'slider-2' , correct? I just renamed 'slider' and I can add as many as I want?

Comment: Correct, at the same time there will be separate 'var select2 =' and same variable will go into slider-2's configuration like: insertAfter(),value:,slide:

Comment: ok I created a new question because i dont understand fully -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291019/multiple-jquery-sliders-attached-to-multiple-select-dropdowns

Comment: sorry @mygm26, i think i confused you. Added answer to your newer question. Please have a look it and let me know if you have any doubts.